# Execute three Mono in parallel as soon they are created, wait for all to finish and collect the results with a specific order/logic

Tags: java, spring, parallel-processing, spring-webflux

I'm new to Spring WebFlux so please, be gentle... I'm sorry if I'm missing some obvious thing but I tried looking for online examples and every time I end up with sequential calls.

I have this situation:

```
Mono<Response> mono1 = webclient1.post()...usual_stuffs....bodyToMono(Response.class);
Mono<Response> mono2 = webclient2.post()...usual_stuffs....bodyToMono(Response.class);
Mono<Response> mono3 = webclient3.post()...usual_stuffs....bodyToMono(Response.class);
```

Response is a class in my project but for this example we can consider them as simple containers of a single List each.

I'd like to:

- Execute them in parallel (as soon I assign them to mono1/mono2/mono3, by calling .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()) maybe?)
- When all are done save the response to resp1, resp2, resp3
- if resp1 has results (the list is not empty) return resp1 else ...
- ... if resp2 has results (the list is not empty) return resp2 else ...
- ... return resp3 (even if its empty)

**How do I achieve this?** (since I failed multiple times)

My first attempt was:

```
Mono<Response> mono1 = webclient1.post()...usual_stuffs....bodyToMono(Response.class).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());
Mono<Response> mono2 = webclient2.post()...usual_stuffs....bodyToMono(Response.class).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());
Mono<Response> mono3 = webclient3.post()...usual_stuffs....bodyToMono(Response.class).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());
ParallelFlux.from(mono1, mono2, mono3).then().block(); // im not sure if this really execute them in parallel
Response resp1 = mono1.block();
Response resp2 = mono2.block();
Response resp3 = mono3.block();
if (resp1.isNotEmpty()) {
    return resp1;
}
if (resp2.isNotEmpty()) {
    return resp2;
}
return resp3;
```

This does not seems to work, does ParallelFlux.from(mono1, mono2, mono3).then().block() really run those monos in parallel? Also why do I need ParallelFlux? Can't I just say "run this mono on a separate thread" as soon I create each mono? Each .block() actually redo the call.... like its re executing the mono... why?

**UPDATE:**

By reading the comments I changed my code to this:

```
Mono<Response> mono1 = webclient1.post()...usual_stuffs....bodyToMono(Response.class).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());
Mono<Response> mono2 = webclient2.post()...usual_stuffs....bodyToMono(Response.class).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());
Mono<Response> mono3 = webclient3.post()...usual_stuffs....bodyToMono(Response.class).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());

Tuple3<Response, Response, Response> all = Mono.zip(mono1, mono2, mono3).block();

Response resp1 = all.getT1();
Response resp2 = all.getT2();
Response resp3 = all.getT3();

if (resp1.hasMessages()) {
    return resp1;
}
if (resp2.hasMessages()) {
    return resp2;
}
return resp3;
```

Now it seems to work. Do I need to do something else or I'm ok with this solution? Should I also change `Mono.zip(mono1, mono2, mono3).block()` in `Mono.zip(mono1, mono2, mono3).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()).block()` ?
p.s. I'm reading the docs again now and I think I should use Schedulers.elastic() insted of Schedulers.parallel().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a mono doesn't automatically execute it. You need a terminal operator like `subscribe` or `block` to trigger the execution (`subscribeOn` is not a terminal operator. You don't need it unless you want to defer your execution to a different thread pool. By default it uses a default thread pool). If you want multiple mono's to run in parallel you can use `zip` operator.

```
Mono<Response> mono1 = webclient1.post()...usual_stuffs....bodyToMono(Response.class).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());
Mono<Response> mono2 = webclient2.post()...usual_stuffs....bodyToMono(Response.class).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());
Mono<Response> mono3 = webclient3.post()...usual_stuffs....bodyToMono(Response.class).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());

return Mono.zip(mono1, mono2, mono3)
        .map(t -> {
            if (t.getT1().isEmpty()) {
                if (t.getT2().isEmpty()) {
                    return t.getT3();
                } else {
                    return t.getT2();
                }
            } else {
                return t.getT1();
            }
        });
```

Note: Calling this doesn't execute and give you result. It gives you back a mono on which you can call a `subscribe()` to get the result.

Comment: Ty for the reply :) at the end I done this:


`Tuple3<Response, Response, Response> all = Mono.zip(mono1, mono2, mono3).block();`

`ResponseValidaDatiContratto resp1 = all.getT1();`

`ResponseValidaDatiContratto resp2 = all.getT2();`

`ResponseValidaDatiContratto resp3 = all.getT3();`

`if (resp1.hasMessages()) return resp1;`

`if (resp2.hasMessages()) return resp2;`

`return resp3;`

Should I also call `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())` after on the `.zip(...)`?

Comment: It wont be needed in general use cases. `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())` will be needed only when you do some resource intensive blocking operations/transformations  which might hold resources in the default pool.

Comment: And in most cases you don't need to use `block()` or `subscribe()`. You will just have to build a reactive chain of operations and hook it up with either a REST controller or others